# Why are my React image imports not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import

PLEASE SEE UPDATE BELOW

This is my first time posting on stack overflow because usually I can find answers but I simply can't this time. I'm using React for the first time in a few months and just trying to show some images on the page. The imports are not working at all.

Here is where I put them

[filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qODZT.png)

I created an index.js inside in order to export all of them at once:

```
const images =
{
image1: require("./001.jpg").default,
image2: require("./002.jpg").default,
image3: require("./003.jpg").default,
image4: require("./004.jpg").default,
image5: require("./005.jpg").default,
image6: require("./006.jpg").default,
image7: require("./007.jpg").default,
image8: require("./008.jpg").default,
image9: require("./009.jpg").default
}


export default images;
```

I also tried similar things with an array (which is what I wanted) and with ES6 imports in case that was the issue.

I then have attempted to use them here:

```
import React from 'react'
import images from "../photos/index.js"
import Photo from "./Photo";

function PhotoList() {

    const photoComponents = Object.values(images).map(
        image => {
            return <Photo photo={image}/>
        }
    )

    return(
        <div>
            {photoComponents}
        </div>
    )

}

export default PhotoList
```

I have also tried to display just a single image using  directly here and that also is broken, so it's not the Photo component that's broken, and apparently not the mapping either. It's just the imports.

And here we have the page. Everything else shows:

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import "./main.css";
import PhotoList from "./Photo";

function mainPage() {
  return (
    <div className="mainPage">
      <h1>Jei Ganiyeva</h1>
      <Navbar/>
      <PhotoList/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default mainPage;
```

And it shows up like this:

[broken image on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqwri.png)

What is up with this? I can't seem to find any answers apart from people importing things wrong which I am not doing. Well, I assume I'm doing something wrong, but not in the way they are.

Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE:

It appears the Photo component is not receiving any props no matter what it is. See here, I have replaced the mapping with passing a simple integer variable and simply showing it as a h1 in Photo:

import React from 'react'
import {images} from "../resources/photoInfo.js"
import Photo from "./Photo";

```
function PhotoList() {

    // const photoComponents = images
    //     .map(image => {
    //         return(
    //             <Photo className="photo" source={image}/>
    //         )
    //     });

    const image = 100;
    
    return <div><Photo source={image}/></div>

}

export default PhotoList

import React from 'react'

function Photo({source}) {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{`The props are ${source}`}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Photo
```

This results in the following screen:

[image: undefined props showing on site]

Comment: the link to `broken image on site` is probably wrong, cause is showing the file structure, could you fix that?

Also, could you provide the implementation of the `Photo` component?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution to this and am answering myself just for a reference for anyone who googles this. However, I doubt anyone will have exactly the same problem.

Basically, in the main page, you can see above that I'm actually importing PhotoList from "./Photo" not "./PhotoList" as intended. This means that the logic held within PhotoList that passed the props to Photo was not being used. This also explains why I never saw anything in the console when I tried to console.log from PhotoList. So, if anyone else does have a mystery problem like this, check whether all parts of your code are being reached at all!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for answering the question (and not just ignore it after you found the solution), to keep stackoverflow clean :-)